# Count the number of indirectly used assemblies in NDepend

Tags: ndepend

I'm trying to count the *indirect* assembly references. The following does not work because IsIndirectlyUsing wants a constant string: "Only constant literal string are accepted as input for IsIndirectlyUsing(string)"

Is there a method to get the *indirect* assemblies used?

````
from a in Assemblies 

let indirectlyUsed = 
  from dep in Assemblies
  let depName = a.FullName
  where a.IsIndirectlyUsing(depName)
  select dep

where a.PDBFound orderby a.AssembliesUsed.Count() descending
select new { a, a.AssembliesUsed, indirectlyUsed, a.NbLinesOfCode, a.NbILInstructions }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NDepend.API](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-api-quickstart) method [FillIterative()](https://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html#ndepend.api%7Endepend.codemodel.extensionmethodshelpers%7Efilliterative.html) is here to help:

```
from a in Assemblies 

let indirectlyUsed = a.AssembliesUsed.FillIterative(
    asms => asms.SelectMany(a1 => a1.AssembliesUsed)).DefinitionDomain

where a.PDBFound orderby indirectlyUsed .Count() descending
select new { a, a.AssembliesUsed, indirectlyUsed, a.NbLinesOfCode, a.NbILInstructions }
```

[image: List assemblies used directly and indirectly]